# Overcome Missing Google Sheets Functions in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Trying to convert or recreate this Google Sheets formula in Excel. What I have is a list of users that may or may not repeat and I am trying to find the number of purchaes, lowest purchase amount, the total price of purchases and the average price of purchases.

Here is my Google Sheets formula that does exactly what I am looking for:

**=QUERY(Data!A2:E,"select A, sum(E), min(D), sum(D), avg(D) group by A label A 'Email', sum(E) 'Length', min(D) 'Lowest Price', sum(D) 'Total', avg(D) 'Average'",0)**

*Source Data Sheet:*

```
Email                Name   Date        Price    Qty
user1@domain1.com    User1  1/19/2014   49.00     1
user1@domain1.com    User1  2/19/2014   49.00     1
user2@domain2.com    User2  6/7/2013    49.00     1
user3@domain3.com    User3  5/25/2014   24.95     1
user4@domain4.com    User4  4/26/2013   49.00     1
user4@domain4.com    User4  5/26/2013   49.00     1
user5@domain5.com    User5  6/17/2014   24.95     1
user5@domain5.com    User5  2/7/2014    49.00     1
user6@domain6.com    User6  3/25/2014   24.95     1
user6@domain6.com    User6  4/7/2014    49.00     1
user6@domain6.com    User6  5/13/2014   49.00     1
user7@domain7.com    User7  10/23/2013  49.00     1
user7@domain7.com    User7  11/23/2013  49.00     1
user8@domain8.com    User8  9/19/2013   24.95     1
user8@domain8.com    User8  3/14/2015   49.00     1
user9@domain9.com    User9  5/1/2013    24.95     1
user9@domain9.com    User9  6/1/2013    49.00     1
user9@domain9.com    User9  7/1/2013    49.00     1
```

*Output Sheet Sheet:*

```
Email              Length     Lowest Price    Total         Average
user1@domain1.com    2           $49.00       $98.00        $49.00
user2@domain2.com    1           $49.00       $49.00        $49.00
user3@domain3.com    1           $24.95       $24.95        $24.95
user4@domain4.com    2           $49.00       $98.00        $49.00
user5@domain5.com    2           $24.95       $73.95        $36.98
user6@domain6.com    3           $24.95       $122.95       $40.98
user7@domain7.com    2           $49.00       $98.00        $49.00
user8@domain8.com    2           $24.95       $73.95        $36.98
user9@domain9.com    3           $24.95       $122.95       $40.98
```

I would prefer no VBA but if that is the only way to make it work then so be it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Pivot Table to get this result.

1. Go to Insert > Pivot Table.
2. Add the Email to Rows, Qty to Values, and add Price to Values 3 times.
3. Right click each Price column > Summarize Values By, and select the appropriate aggregation.
4. You can change the column headers and cell number formats by simply editing the cells, or through the Value Field Settings.

[image: Pivot Table Example]